# SQlite3 is there anyway to know the amount of entries that have been added?

Tags: php, sqlite

I was looking into using a database to store a generated link to that database entry that holds more information about the database entry. So you would see a bit of the database, then click on the entry and open a new page that holds more information about that entry.

What I was looking for was something to keep track of the amount of entries that have been entered, even if one of the entries have been removed. I know SQlite3 has count, but I haven't seen anything that would keep track of this. I was thinking in order reach my goal I would have to just set a counter and write it to a file and pull that counter when I am making a new entry, just wondering if anyone know something else I can do instead of reading/writing a file for one number.

Should be noted this is on a server that can be shutdown and restarted, the user must enter in the information that goes into the database and the server will log it for the user. And I don't want to every repeat the same entry number.

I have mainly used PHP, HTML, and Python for the current project I am working on.

Comment: One simple answer is a table trigger that would update a separate audit table, keeping an audit of records entered, updated, deleted.  Other details of the question are not completely clear.

Comment: You certainly wouldn't have to use a separate file.  Just create a [temp] table to keep track of whatever accounting you like.

Comment: Interesting, I've seen this implemented in apps as 'post save' or 'pre save' and always wondered how it worked. Posted some info on CREATE TRIGGERS from the sqlite docs as an answer. Looks like postgres has TRIGGER too postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Super cool, I will look into triggers. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this out of curiosity because you can do 'post save' and 'pre save' in most ORM-based webapps.

> "A trigger may be specified to fire whenever a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE of a particular database table occurs"
>
> https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER aft_insert AFTER INSERT ON emp_details
BEGIN
INSERT INTO emp_log(emp_id,salary,edittime)
         VALUES(NEW.employee_id,NEW.salary,current_date);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer I was looking for was built into SQLite3, which is the best kind of answer.[Auto Increment in SQlite3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm) allows for me to do what I was looking for. It will keep track of the amount of entries that have been added meaning I will be able to generate a link from the ROWID that I set to Auto Increment and not have a chance to repeat that it again.